# Flutter app not compatible with all android tv / media boxes

Tags: android, flutter, compatibility

I have a working app made with Flutter.
Some of the android TV / Media boxes can't install the app with the following error:
This app isn't compatible with your media box.

Altough minSdk is 21, targetSdk 26, and the android media box is android 6.0.
I have other media boxes that are working just fine with the app.

What could be the problem?

Someone?

Answer (score 0):

Android 6.0 is API level 23.
If you app is minSdk 26, this is why you can't install it on your Android TV.

Comment: Sorry, meant targetSdk 26 and minSdk 21